# How to make a simple to-do list type thing

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a to-do list like "app" that allows you to add and remove an item from the list. The code that I currently have allows you to add and remove, but if you add the same "to-do item", it just adds it twice. I would like it so that when I add the same item as one that is already on the list, it says "x2" next to the item. I also would like it so that when you press the x button for the item, if it is there with the "x2", then make it just one again.

Here's my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDIV" class="header">
  <h2 style="margin:5px">My To Do List</h2>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li>Hit the gym</li>
  <li class="checked">Pay bills</li>
  <li>Meet George</li>
  <li>Buy eggs</li>
  <li>Read a book</li>
  <li>Organize office</li>
</ul>

<script>
// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Now would be a good time to start refactoring your code duplication before starting to add new features. **[todomvc](http://todomvc.com/)** might also help. There is a vanilla js example app near bottom  as well as numerous framework versions

Comment: todomvc seems good but isn't what I'm looking for. I really just want to know how I can do what I asked in my question with the code I already have.

Comment: have several choices...store data in array and work from that or you have to iterate through all the elements again to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

Here we are checking if a to-do item is already existing in the list.

if yes then add a span with counter value for this in the X span and keep on add ing on this counter if same item added again.

Deletion logic will be also changed and will check if the counter span is present, if yes then do a decrement on the counter . If the counter is 1 then hide the parent div as per your current logic.

```css
.close {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myDIV" class="header">
    <h2 style="margin:5px">My To Do List</h2>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
    <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
  </div>

  <ul id="myUL">
    <li>Hit the gym</li>
    <li class="checked">Pay bills</li>
    <li>Meet George</li>
    <li>Buy eggs</li>
    <li>Read a book</li>
    <li>Organize office</li>
  </ul>

  <script>
    // Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
    var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
      var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
      var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
      span.className = "close";
      span.appendChild(txt);
      myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
    }

     // Click on a close button to hide the current list item
    var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
      close[i].onclick = function() {
        var div = this.parentElement;
        if (this.querySelector(".counter") == null) {
          div.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          var count = parseInt(this.querySelector(".counter").textContent);

          if (count <= 1) {
            div.style.display = "none";
            count--;
            this.querySelector(".counter").textContent = count;
          } else {
            count--;
            this.querySelector(".counter").textContent = count;
          }

        }
      }
    }

     // Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
    var list = document.querySelector('ul');
    list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
      if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
      }
    }, false);

     // Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
    function newElement() {


      var isExisting = false;
      var existingArray = [];
      var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
      var list = document.querySelectorAll("#myUL li");

      [].forEach.call(list, function(el) {
        [].forEach.call(el.childNodes, function(elem) {
          if (elem.nodeType == 3) {
            if (elem.nodeValue == inputValue) {
              isExisting = true;
              var span = elem.nextElementSibling;
              if (span.querySelector(".counter") == null) {
                var countSpan = document.createElement("span");
                var counter = 2;
                if (elem.parentElement.style.display == "none") {
                  counter = 1;
                  elem.parentElement.style.display = "list-item";
                }


                var count = document.createTextNode(counter);
                countSpan.className = "counter";
                countSpan.appendChild(count);
                span.appendChild(countSpan);

              } else {

                elem.parentElement.style.display = "list-item";
                var count = parseInt(span.querySelector(".counter").textContent);
                count++;
                span.querySelector(".counter").textContent = count;
              }


            }

          }
        });
      });


      if (isExisting === false) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
        li.appendChild(t);
        if (inputValue === '') {
          alert("You must write something!");
        } else {
          document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
        }
        document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

        var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
        var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
        span.className = "close";
        span.appendChild(txt);
        li.appendChild(span);

        for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
          close[i].onclick = function() {

            var div = this.parentElement;
            if (this.querySelector(".counter") == null) {
              div.style.display = "none";
            } else {
              var count = parseInt(this.querySelector(".counter").textContent);

              if (count <= 1) {
                div.style.display = "none";
                count--;
                this.querySelector(".counter").textContent = count;
              } else {
                count--;
                this.querySelector(".counter").textContent = count;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```